# Can I add some value to an int in a database without knowing its current value

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say I have the following table

players

```
player_id score
1       - 300
2       - 400
```

can I do a query that will add 10 to the score of a player?

because right now all I can think of is query the db, get the score, add 10 to it, then query the db and replace 300 with 310?

PS: Im new to SQL

Comment: Since you are new to sql, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in Ten Minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:-

```
UPDATE players 
SET score = score + 10 
WHERE player_id = 1
```

Also check [UPDATE in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: will do in 10 minutes when the system allows me to :)

Comment: can I replace "10" with a value from another table? for example "set score = score + points.pointsForAGoal"

Comment: Yes, but the syntax would be different.

Comment: Yes you can but with a different syntac

Comment: is this the syntax: "set score = score + points.pointsForAGoal"

Comment: points is a table where I've defined how many points are awarded for a certain action and "pointsForAGoal" is the value with a number of points. I think this is supposed to  be a foreign key?

Comment: Then you may try to get the value of points in a variable and then update the same. Something like `select @point = points from mytable where column1 = 'some condition'` and then update the value of score with `set score = score + @point`

Comment: @J.Kowalski:- Yes if you want to do that in one single query then just put the select query in place of the variable I have used

Comment: do I put it within braces, like this? set score = score + (select points from mytable where column1 = 'some condition' limit 1)

Comment: @J.Kowalski:- Instead of * select the column which you want to add. Rest is fine!

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE players SET score = score + 10 WHERE player_id = 1
```